# From Access 2013 to query SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I use the below connection and ADO recordset to get SQL Server 2012 data by Access 2013 VBA code.  The recorset is an query(strQuery) which join couple SQL tables together.  I am not familiar with the conenction with SQL Server.  The conenction string is copied from Excel Data connection properties.

```
Dim ADOConn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

str = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;" & _
  "Initial Catalog=PlanSystem;Data Source=RD\SQLServer;Use Procedure for Prepare=1;" & _
  "Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Workstation ID=RD;" & _
  "Use Encryption for Data=False;Tag with column collation when possible=False"

ADOConn.Open str
ADOConn.CursorLocation = adUseClient

strQuery = "SELECT * FROM Table1 JOIN Table2 ON ... "
rs.Open strQuery, ADOConn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText
```

How can I rewrite the recordset connection to a query which I can set qdf.SQL to SQL Server tables?  Below is the code I can set query to local table.  I need a similiar code which I can set query to SQL Server.  The query SQL will be passed to SQL Server and return the join linked data back to query only.

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef

Set db = CurrentDb
Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("qryPlan")
qdf.SQL = strQuery
```

Comment: Did you try http://www.Connectionstrings.com?

Comment: U want to pass that connection string to querydefs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Set Connection String :

```
 sConnString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source=RD\SQLServer;" & _
                  "Initial Catalog=PlanSystem;" & _
                  "Integrated Security=SSPI;"

 sConnString2 =   "ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=RD\SQLServer;DATABASE=PlanSystem;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"

Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("qryPlan")
qdf.Connect = sConnString2 
qdf.SQL = strQuery

Also ,
Set qdfNew = db.CreateQueryDef(strQueryName, strQuery)
qdfNew.Connect = sConnString2 
qdfNew.Close
```

Comment: Run-Time error '3125' on qdf.connect = str code.  It says str is not a valid name. Str is the connection properties and I use it to open ADO recodrset without issue.

Comment: 3125 means syntax error. Please change the connections string , see the update.

Comment: I use "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=RD\SQLServer;Initial Catalog=PlanSystem;Integrated Security=SSPI;" to connect and I got Run time error '3305' Invalid connection string in pass-through query.  The source name is copied from server login.  It is correct. same error if I use SQLOLEDB.1

Comment: are u able to connect to sql server with windows authentication ?

Comment: Yes, please refer to my post.  I use str to open ADO recordset.  I can read it.

Comment: OK . Can u try the second connection string ? it is using ODBC .

Comment: run time error '438' Object does not support this property or method.  Will it be different on SQL Server 2014 and SQL Server 2012?  I have different version on two locations.  Currently I am using 2014.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131312/discussion-between-fakeisme-and-yellowlarry).

Comment: Guess Trusted_Connection=True should be made as Trusted_Connection=Yes .